# why line break is not working in php code

Tags: php, html, syntax-error, line-breaks

I have added a line break in this piece of PHP code, but it's getting a syntax error.
Does PHP not allow breaks in its code?

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>


    </head>
    <body>
</body>

<?php
define("Value_of_Pi", 3.14);
define ("Gravity_Value", 9.8);

echo "Pi value is".Value_of_Pi; 
<br/>
echo "Gravity Value is".Gravity_Value;
?>  
</html>
```

Comment: Not the `HTML`. You can try `echo '\r\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use \r\n if you want to break line within php.

```
<?php
define("Value_of_Pi", 3.14);
define ("Gravity_Value", 9.8);

echo "Pi value is".Value_of_Pi. "\r\n"; 
echo "Gravity Value is".Gravity_Value;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<br/>` is not valid PHP syntax. You could either have the `<br/>` outside the PHP block:

```
<?php
define("Value_of_Pi", 3.14);
define ("Gravity_Value", 9.8);

echo "Pi value is".Value_of_Pi; 
?> 
<!-- PHP block terminated -->
<br/>
<!-- New PHP block opened: -->
<?PHP
echo "Gravity Value is".Gravity_Value;
?>
```

Or just echo it from PHP:

```
<?php
define("Value_of_Pi", 3.14);
define ("Gravity_Value", 9.8);

echo "Pi value is".Value_of_Pi; 
echo "<br/>"; # Here!
echo "Gravity Value is".Gravity_Value;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `echo '<br/>';`.

This is because you can either write HTML code or PHP within the specific sections.

You are currently in a PHP code section so you can only write PHP code there that will be valid.

`<br/>` is not a valid PHP code but HTML. However, because you are within `<?php ?>` it is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below instead:

```
echo '<br/>';
```

`<br/>` is an HTML tag hence the syntax error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` is html and must be echoed within php, like so:

```
<?php
define("Value_of_Pi", 3.14);
define ("Gravity_Value", 9.8);

echo "Pi value is".Value_of_Pi; 
echo "<br/>";
echo "Gravity Value is".Gravity_Value;
?>
```

You can also use `\r\n` in php like so:

```
echo "Pi value is".Value_of_Pi. "\r\n";
```